# Why is my checkbox array returing a length of zero in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am dynamically generating checkboxes from my database using jquery ajax to call my web api. The problem is that I am trying to get the length of the checkbox array but constantly receiving an array length of zero when i debug. Please what might be wrong with my code.
**HTML CODE**

```
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Add Role Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Role Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="well">
                                    <fieldset id="appName">

                                    </fieldset>

                                </div>
                                <input id="saveUrl" type="button" value="Add Role" class="btn btn-success pull-right" />
                            </div>

                        </form>

                    </div>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:61768/api/users/GetUrls',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(localStorage.getItem('ApplicationId') + ":" + localStorage.getItem('ApiKey'))
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (Object.keys(data).length == 0) {
                    alert("Ewoo");
                } else {

                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        var input = ('<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' + value.Id + ' />' + value.UrlName + '</label><br>');
                        $('#appName').append(input); //Where I generate the checkboxes
                    });
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("DonDy");
            }
        });
        var $checkboxes = $('input[name="chk[]"]:checked'); //Checkbox array
        $('#saveUrl').click(function () {
            if ($checkboxes.length > 0) {
                alert("Good");

            } else {
                alert("Bad"); //Result.
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

The result of click the save button is alerting bad

Comment: Ajax calls are asynchronous. Meaning your `$('#saveUrl').click` might get executed before the ajax call might have fetched the checkboxes. Try adding that code block into success handler of the ajax call.

Comment: what @kaushik94 mention is quite true, as it is `async`, is better to move the click event into the success call, and +, you might need to bind the`click` event to document instead of the checkbox click, as the dynamic generate checkbox might not in `DOM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code checkbox is getting appended but you are not checking the checkbox

```
  var input = ('<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' + value.Id + ' />' + value.UrlName + '</label><br>');
```

Here you are checking length of checked checkbox..hence alerting to bad :

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[name="chk[]"]:checked');
```

Try this and that to inside save url click fucntion:

```
 $('#saveUrl').click(function () {
    var $checkboxes = $('input[name="chk[]"]');
                if ($checkboxes.length > 0) {
                    alert("Good");

                } else {
                    alert("Bad"); //Result.
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are populating/creating checkbox inside an AJAX call, you should have `$checkboxes` **inside** the `#saveUrl` function, because before that, it would be empty when the JS is loaded. You need this variable when the `#saveUrl` is clicked, hence it should check for the `checked` inputs when the `#saveUrl` is triggered:

```
$('#saveUrl').click(function() {
  var $checkboxes = $('input[name="chk[]"]:checked'); //Checkbox array
  if ($checkboxes.length > 0) {
    alert("Good");

  } else {
    alert("Bad"); //Result.
  }
});
```